# MySQL SELECT X(location) returning unexpected number / format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, geospatial

When I run this on my 'location' column (POINT data type in my 'journeys' table) I seem to get an unexpected number format returned (PHP / Codeigniter):

```
$this->db->select('X(location)');
$query = $this->db->get('journeys');
```

For example, I get -5.52512112317928e-305 when I would expect something like 51.5...

Values for 'location' are inserted as follows:

```
$this->db->set('location','geomfromtext("POINT(lat lng)")',false);
```

I'm sure its a simple number formatting issue but I'm stumped.

Comment: In the line `geomfromtext("POINT(lat lng)")`, are you actually inputting a real lat and lng there? I assume that's just a placeholder for the sake of this question, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, as per your answer I am indeed inserting real lat / lng values there. I'll have a go at using a specific precision later...

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you are entering your data points:

```
$this->db->set('location','geomfromtext("POINT(lat lng)")',false);
```

I assume that you are not exactly showing us the code you are using, and it looks more like this:

```
$this->db->set('location','geomfromtext("POINT('.$lat.' '.$lng.')")',false);
```

Perhaps you should nicely format your input depending on what kind of precision you want. Maybe like this:

```
$this->db->set('location','geomfromtext("POINT('.number_format($lat,6,'.','').' '.number_format($lng,6,'.','').')")',false);
```